# Laravel on Raspberry Pi : PDOException could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I've installed Laravel on my Raspberry Pi 2 using PHP 5.6.13 (Raspbian OS). Everything has worked well until I attempted to do a migration with `php artisan migrate`. That resulted in the error `[PDOException] could not find driver`.

I haven't been able to figure out what I'm missing. I've installed the `php5-mysql` module using apt. I've set the `extension_dir` in `php.ini` as well as `extension=pdo_mysql.so`.

I know I can use Homestead but I would prefer to understand what is missing in my current set up, so please refrain from suggesting Homestead.

Does anyone have any idea what I could be missing? It's driving me crazy!

Comment: Just checking: do you also have mysql enabled as the default database driver in your config, and have you restarted apache and php and verified that they imported the extension correctly?

Comment: try phpinfo() to check pdo_mysql is loaded or not, check under mysqlnd using phpinfo

Comment: I've checked phpinfo and pdo_mysql is there. Mysql is the default database driver in the laravel config as well. I'm really at a loss here.

Comment: Have the same problem. Any solution yet?